# How to configure Nautilus to open a terminal

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, command-line

Let us say I am viewing the `/media/fun/videos/chucknorris` folder in Nautilus. How can I configure Nautilus so by pressing a Key it opens a terminal and this terminal defaults opened directory is the folder am viewing in Nautilus (In this case the chucknorris folder). So if I open the terminal it should show me am in the `/media/fun/videos/chucknorris` directory.

Note that the terminal window should not be embedded in Nautilus, instead it should be another Window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just install [nautilus-open-terminal](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/nautilus-open-terminal).

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
```

Then you can open a terminal by right-clicking in your folder. (It will open in the right directory and in a separate window.

For a keyboard shortcut see the post on [webupd8:](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/09/how-to-set-up-nautilus-open-in-terminal.html)

Comment: Before accepting am one of those users that like to use more the keyboard instead of the mouse. Any option to set a key to open the current folder in a terminal using Nautilus.